# Drop down menu gives error

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, responsive-design

So I'm programming a site for school. I want to make a menu which is responsive and folds down. I can't let it fold up or fold down. I used JavaScript, Css3, and Html5. It will probably won't be possible to do it with only JavaScript, Css3, and Html5. I will accept other programming languages but I would rather do it with those three.

Javascript:

```
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += "responsive";
} else {
    x.className = "topnav";
}
}
```

Html5:

```
<body>

 <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
 <ul class="topnav">
  <li><a href="index.html"><img class="home" alt="home" src="http://projekpeople.com/wp/student2/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2015/09/home-logo-hi.png"></a></li>   
  <li><a class="subjects" href="webdesign_important.html">IMPORTANT SUBJECTS</a></li>
  <li><a class="subjects" href="webdesign_opdrachten.html">OPDRACHTEN</a></li>
  <li><a class="subjects" href="webdesign_css.html">CSS FILES</a></li>
  <li><a class="subjects" href="webdesign_donate.html">DONATE</a></li>
  <li><a class="subjects" href="webdesign_aboutme.html ">ABOUT ME</a></li>
  <li><a class="subjects" href="webdesign_form.html">FORM</a>
   <li class="icon">
<a class="menu" href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size: 20px;"    onclick="myFunction()">☰</a>
  </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
```

Css3:

```
.topnav ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #FFF;
text-align: right;
float: right;
}

ul.topnav li {float: right;}

ul.topnav li a {
display: inline-block;
color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
text-align: right;
padding: 16px 20px;
text-decoration: none;
transition: 0.3s;
font-size: 17px;
list-style-type: none;
height: 25px;
}

ul.topnav li a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

ul.topnav li.icon {display: none;}

@media screen and (max-width:1200px) {
ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
ul.topnav li.icon {
float: right;
display: inline-block;
list-style-type: none;
}
}

@media screen and (max-width:1300px) {
ul.topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 0;
list-style-type: none;
}
ul.topnav.responsive li {
float: none;
display: inline;
list-style-type: none;
}
ul.topnav.responsive li a {
display: block;
text-align: left;
list-style-type: none;
}
}
.menu {
text-decoration: none;
list-style-type: none;
height: 20px;
width: auto;
}

ul.topnav {
text-align: center;

}
```

It is probably a stupid mistake, but still thank you for the guy who took the time to help me! :D

Comment: If your site is huge, I recomend you to use a css framework like bootstrap, materialize css, fundation, etc... those frameworks are responsive, you only have to use the framework rules.

Comment: You are trying to add "responsive" to the `div` but your css is checking for this class on the `ul` . Also, you are adding a string to the `className` to make "topnavresponsive" you need to add a space in to separate them.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a space before 'responsive'

Like this:

```
x.className += " responsive"
```

classes are separated by a space

Hope that's it. :-).

Comment: I tried it. Still doesn't work :(  the link is : https://webdesign-trulezzz.c9users.io/index.html

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps you: http://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/GrJmVq

The fixes I made were:

- you want a space in your javascript on the line  `x.className += " responsive";` , as noted earlier by [Mathew Wilcoxson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/266375/matthew-wilcoxson) and [Jonathan Wood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7114773/jonathan-wood)
- secondly there was a problem with where this JS is adding the 'responsive' class. Your CSS is expecting in to be applied to `<ul class="topnav">`  but the JS is adding it to `<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">`

My solution was to move the `id="myTopnav"` to the ul, there are other ways of achieving the same result though.

I notice that your CSS still needs work because I notice that the icon for the mobile nav jumps around, but hopefully this gets you moving again.

Good luck!